# TensorFlow GPU problem 'libnvinfer.so.7' and ' 'libnvinfer.so.7'' could not load

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, lib

I installed TensorFlow under [WSL 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux#WSL_2), [Ubuntu 22.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_22.04_LTS_(Jammy_Jellyfish)) (Jammy Jellyfish), I followed the instructions in *[Install TensorFlow with pip](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip)*.

*I also installed Nvidia drivers for Windows and in my other WSL 2, I use GPU-supported simulation program.

Everything seemed OK. I didn't get any error message during installation, but when I imported TensorFlow in Python 3, I got this error:

```
2023-02-12 14:49:58.544771: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.7'; dlerror: libnvrtc.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2023-02-12 14:49:58.544845: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.7'; dlerror: libnvinfer_plugin.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2023-02-12 14:49:58.544874: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly.
```

I searched my libnvinfer_plugin.so.7 files:

```
sudo find / -name libnvinfer.so.7  2> /dev/null
```

and I found them in this directory:

```
cat /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvinfer.so.7
```

and I added this directory to LD_LIBRARY_PATH like in *[Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.7'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74956134/could-not-load-dynamic-library-libnvinfer-so-7)*, but nothing changed. Still TensorFlow is working, but I can't use the GPU.

nvidia-smi:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 515.65.01    Driver Version: 516.94       CUDA Version: 11.7     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  On   | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   43C    P0    22W /  N/A |      0MiB /  6144MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

nvcc--version:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2023 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Jan__6_16:45:21_PST_2023
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.0, V12.0.140
Build cuda_12.0.r12.0/compiler.32267302_0
```

*The TensorFlow version is: 2.11.0

So, how can I fix this problem?

Comment: TensorRT and the libnvinfer libraries are not needed for GPU support, you probably have a different problem.

Comment: yes but I couldn't figure out what it was.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I changed version and the problem was solved:

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow==2.8
```

*Note*: When I use v2.10, I get the same error message. v2.8 is stable now.

Comment: Confirming this fixed a "Data Science Virtual Machine - Ubuntu 20.04" installation on a "Standard NC6s v3 (6 vcpus, 112 GiB memory)" VM, on Azure. Adding on this, you should downgrade `tensorflow-gpu` too (and possibly other `tensorflow-*` stuff).

Answer (score 1):

I have used following sequence of commands and it worked -
Install TensorFlow-2.11.0 on Ubuntu 22.04 with GPU (RTX 3080ti and RTX 2060) support

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
nvcc --version
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
sudo apt install python3-dev python3-pip
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip3 install --upgrade pip
nvcc --version
nvidia-smi
pip3 --version
sudo pip3 install nvidia-cudnn-cu11==8.5.0.96
sudo pip3 install tensorflow==2.11.0
sudo apt install nvidia-cudnn
python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"
```

Comment: I tried this before I asked this question it didn't help. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Sadidul Islam Your above steps worked, however I was getting empty brackets [] back on the last step and additionally I ran this code to verify the GPU `python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print('Num GPUs Available: ', len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))"` was giving me no GPUs. I had to additionally follow the steps listed [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/53341#issuecomment-1166532019) and finally it returns my 1 GPU being available.