# Cuda 12 + tf-nightly 2.12: Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used, while every checking is fine and in torch it works

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

- **tf-nightly version** = 2.12.0-dev2023203
- **Python version** = 3.10.6
- **CUDA drivers version** = 525.85.12
- **CUDA version** = 12.0
- **Cudnn version** = 8.5.0
- I am using **Linux** (x86_64, Ubuntu 22.04)
- I am coding in **Visual Studio Code** on a **venv** virtual environment

I am trying to run some models on the GPU (NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050) using tensorflow nightly 2.12 (to be able to use Cuda 12.0). The problem that I have is that apparently every checking that I am making seems to be correct, but in the end the script is not able to detect the GPU. I've dedicated a lot of time trying to see what is happening and nothing seems to work, so any advice or solution will be more than welcomed. The GPU seems to be working for torch as you can see at the very end of the question.

I will show some of the most common checkings regarding CUDA that I did (Visual Studio Code terminal), I hope you find them useful:

1. **Check CUDA version:**

   `$ nvcc --version`

   ```
   nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
   Copyright (c) 2005-2023 NVIDIA Corporation
   Built on Fri_Jan__6_16:45:21_PST_2023
   Cuda compilation tools, release 12.0, V12.0.140
   Build cuda_12.0.r12.0/compiler.32267302_0
   ```
2. **Check if the connection with the CUDA libraries is correct:**

   `$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

   ```
   /usr/cuda/lib
   ```
3. **Check nvidia drivers for the GPU and check if GPU is readable for the venv:**

   `$ nvidia-smi`

   ```
   +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
   | NVIDIA-SMI 525.85.12    Driver Version: 525.85.12    CUDA Version: 12.0     |
   |-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
   | GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
   | Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
   |                               |                      |               MIG M. |
   |===============================+======================+======================|
   |   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  On   | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
   | N/A   40C    P5     6W /  20W |     46MiB /  4096MiB |     22%      Default |
   |                               |                      |                  N/A |
   +-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

   +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
   | Processes:                                                                  |
   |  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
   |        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
   |=============================================================================|
   |    0   N/A  N/A      1356      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 45MiB |
   +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
   ```
4. **Add cuda/bin PATH and Check it:**

   `$ export PATH="/usr/local/cuda/bin:$PATH"`

   `$ echo $PATH`

   ```
   /usr/local/cuda-12.0/bin:/home/victus-linux/Escritorio/MasterThesis_CODE/to_share/venv_master/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin
   ```
5. **Custom function to check if CUDA is correctly installed: [[function by Sherlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31326015/how-to-verify-cudnn-installation)]**

   ```bash
   function lib_installed() { /sbin/ldconfig -N -v $(sed 's/:/ /' <<< $LD_LIBRARY_PATH) 2>/dev/null | grep $1; }
   function check() { lib_installed $1 && echo "$1 is installed" || echo "ERROR: $1 is NOT installed"; }
   check libcuda
   check libcudart
   ```

   ```
   libcudart.so.12 -> libcudart.so.12.0.146
           libcuda.so.1 -> libcuda.so.525.85.12
           libcuda.so.1 -> libcuda.so.525.85.12
           libcudadebugger.so.1 -> libcudadebugger.so.525.85.12
   libcuda is installed
           libcudart.so.12 -> libcudart.so.12.0.146
   libcudart is installed
   ```
6. **Custom function to check if Cudnn is correctly installed: [[function by Sherlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31326015/how-to-verify-cudnn-installation)]**

   ```bash
   function lib_installed() { /sbin/ldconfig -N -v $(sed 's/:/ /' <<< $LD_LIBRARY_PATH) 2>/dev/null | grep $1; }
   function check() { lib_installed $1 && echo "$1 is installed" || echo "ERROR: $1 is NOT installed"; }
   check libcudnn
   ```

   ```
           libcudnn_cnn_train.so.8 -> libcudnn_cnn_train.so.8.8.0
           libcudnn_cnn_infer.so.8 -> libcudnn_cnn_infer.so.8.8.0
           libcudnn_adv_train.so.8 -> libcudnn_adv_train.so.8.8.0
           libcudnn.so.8 -> libcudnn.so.8.8.0
           libcudnn_ops_train.so.8 -> libcudnn_ops_train.so.8.8.0
           libcudnn_adv_infer.so.8 -> libcudnn_adv_infer.so.8.8.0
           libcudnn_ops_infer.so.8 -> libcudnn_ops_infer.so.8.8.0
   libcudnn is installed
   ```

So, once I did these previous checkings I used a script to evaluate if everything was finally ok and then the following error appeared:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

print(f'\nTensorflow version = {tf.__version__}\n')
print(f'\n{tf.config.list_physical_devices("GPU")}\n')
```

```
2023-03-02 12:05:09.463343: I tensorflow/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:28] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
2023-03-02 12:05:09.489911: I tensorflow/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:28] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
2023-03-02 12:05:09.490522: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-03-02 12:05:10.066759: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT

Tensorflow version = 2.12.0-dev20230203

2023-03-02 12:05:10.748675: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:996] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2023-03-02 12:05:10.771263: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1956] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...

[]
```

**Extra check:** I tried to run a checking script on torch and in here it worked so I guess the problem is related with tensorflow/tf-nightly

```py
import torch

print(f'\nAvailable cuda = {torch.cuda.is_available()}')

print(f'\nGPUs availables = {torch.cuda.device_count()}')

print(f'\nCurrent device = {torch.cuda.current_device()}')

print(f'\nCurrent Device location = {torch.cuda.device(0)}')

print(f'\nName of the device = {torch.cuda.get_device_name(0)}')
```

```
Available cuda = True

GPUs availables = 1

Current device = 0

Current Device location = <torch.cuda.device object at 0x7fbe26fd2ec0>

Name of the device = NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Laptop GPU
```

Please, if you know something that might help solve this issue, don't hesitate on telling me.

Comment: Hmm note that pip3 install torch brings a lot of cuda 11 packages.

Comment: tf.sysconfig.get_build_info() shows cuda 11, does it? My guess is that there is not a ship with cuda12

Comment: @arivero That's the output of tf.sysconfig.get_build_info(): _OrderedDict([('cpu_compiler', '/dt9/usr/bin/gcc'), ('cuda_compute_capabilities', ['sm_35', 'sm_50', 'sm_60', 'sm_70', 'sm_75', 'compute_80']), ('cuda_version', '11.8'), ('cudnn_version', '8'), ('is_cuda_build', True), ('is_rocm_build', False), ('is_tensorrt_build', True)])_ . **Cuda_version is 11.8** as you mentioned. What I don't get is how it is possible that? Taking into account that the **tf nightly version was supposed to be compatible with Cuda 12**.

Comment: Yes, I see the problem, because of that I have bountied the question, in the hope that someone with knowledge can tell us if tf nightly can opt between 11 and 12 automagically or not.

Comment: Just see this [commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/3de44168950a5972ba4cfa7e3c6cbf4cffa67fe6) that tf-nightly moved to CUDA 12.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think that, as of March 2023, the only tensorflow distribution for cuda 12 is the docker package from NVIDIA.

A tf package for cuda 12 should show the following info

```
>>> tf.sysconfig.get_build_info() 
OrderedDict([('cpu_compiler', '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-11'), 
('cuda_compute_capabilities', ['compute_86']), 
('cuda_version', '12.0'), ('cudnn_version', '8'), 
('is_cuda_build', True), ('is_rocm_build', False), ('is_tensorrt_build', True)])
```

But if we run tf.sysconfig.get_build_info() on any tensorflow package installed via pip, it stills tells that cuda_version is 11.x

So your alternatives are:

- install docker with the nvidia cloud instructions and run one of the
  recent containers
- compile tensorflow from source, either nightly or last release. Caveat, it takes a lot of RAM and some time, as all good compilations do, and the occasional error to be corrected on the run. In my case, to define kFP8, the new 8-bits float.
- wait

Comment: Note I am not very sure about how compatibility forward works. For instance I have a build that claims cuda 11.2 and it is working on a mixed install of 11.8 and 12.0

Comment: A month later, and I could now switch from pip to arch repository versions by first uninstalling the pip tensorflow packages and then running `sudo pacman -S tensorflow-cuda python-tensorflow-cuda`. This gives me `'cuda_version', '12.1'` and fixes the `'libcudart.so.11.0'` loading error.

Comment: Another option is to install cuda-11-8 from [link](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11-8-0-download-archive) `https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11-8-0-download-archive` (for example). If you use WSL2, the CUDA installation from Windows needs to match the one from Linux distro you are running under WSL2. It worked for me with less headache than compiling TensorFlow or using docker.

Answer (score 8):

"I experienced the same thing, and it can be resolved by installing TensorFlowRT."

1. pip3 install nvidia-tensorrt
2. check the libnvinfer.* file link once again, and make sure that the LD_LIBRARY_PATH points to the installation directory."
3. refer: [Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.7'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74956134/could-not-load-dynamic-library-libnvinfer-so-7)

After all the libraries are fixed, then the GPU output will be visible.
GPU visible:

[image: GPU visible]

Comment: Tensor RT was not the problem in my case. It seems that @arivero answer points in the right direction

Comment: I think the same. Still, 50 points awarded because it could be useful for others

Comment: Not useful, it doesn't solve the problem. Can you please elaborate on how you were able to "bypass" the requirement for a different cuda version?

Comment: This might work on older graphics cards with Ubuntu Linux. I have a GTX 1050 Ti. The install command lagged for a minute and then finished. I restarted the terminal and was able to list my GPU device.

Answer (score 5):

An easier and more current solution - simply installing using:

```
pip3 install tensorflow[and-cuda]
```

installs the cuda-11 libraries and tensorflow without any issues for me (ubuntu 22.04, RTX-4090).

Comment: Thank you, this is the only thing that fixed it for me with CUDA 12.1 running on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add as another alternative, the official `pip3 install tensorflow` also doesn't work with CUDA 12, so my solution was to just go back to CUDA 11:

```
sudo apt install cuda-11-8
```

Tensorflow now works.

Comment: Sorry Ken. Voting down because I was clear enough on the initial question about what you say here. From the very beginning I was using a tf-nightly version so that I could use CUDA 12 (because precisely at that moment tensorflow was not supporting CUDA 11). Maybe your answer makes sense on another question. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exaxt same issue on my ubuntu 22.04, and I've got to downgrade nvidia drivers and cuda toolkit, and then on the venv install python 3.10 with  tensorflow==2.12.0.

steps I've take the following steps:

1. Remove my previus cuda-tool-kit

   sudo apt-get --purge remove "*cuda*" "*cublas*" "*cufft*" "*cufile*" "*curand*" "*cusolver*" "*cusparse*" "*gds-tools*" "*npp*" "*nvjpeg*" "nsight*" "*nvvm*"

2)Downgrade the nvidia drivers to nvidia-drivers-470 (not the server meta-package, only the proprietary one) you can do it on the additional drivers options on ubuntu UI

3. Download the nvidia-tool-kit 11.8 from [Nvidia](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11-8-0-download-archive?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Ubuntu&target_version=22.04) and select the runfile  (local) not the deb(local) I've got problems with that one.
   then sudo sh that file.
   -copy the path as was suggested before into your .bashrc

Don't worry of your nvidia-smi show an updated CUDA version the important is that when you vncc --version on your terminal shows the 11.8 cuda version

4)Download the cudnn suggested for cuda 11.x and for tensorflow [Here](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive). Should be the Download cuDNN v8.6.0 (October 3rd, 2022), for CUDA 11.x Local installer for linux x84_64 (tar), not the (deb) version, I've experienced some problems with the deb one too.

then tar -xvf the file and:

```
$ sudo cp cudnn-*-archive/include/cudnn*.h /usr/local/cuda-11.8/include 
$ sudo cp -P cudnn-*-archive/lib/libcudnn* /usr/local/cuda-11.8/lib64 
$ sudo chmod a+r /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn*.h /usr/local/cuda-11.8/lib64/libcudnn*
```

as is suggested on point 1.3.1 on [Nvidia Cudnn Installation Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html), and take care of directing the copy to cuda-11.8 :)

5)Then I make my venv on conda:

```
conda create -n tf python==3.10
conda activate tf
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install -U setuptools wheel
```

6. Install tensor flow

   pip install tensorflow==2.12.0

By doing so I solve that problems and tensorflow starts to recognizing my gpu, but istill trying to find a solution to NUMA nodes that appears as -1 value :( if someone have some insights on this, would be appreciated :)
Hope this could work for you, I really spend some time installing and uninstalling drivers, cuda tool kits and cudnn versions on my machine, and finally this works on mine, only by doing the tar installation way, really can't say why but worked finally :)
Have a nice one!

Answer (score 0):

This may help where I faced the same issue.

First, install Python 3.9 or a higher version. You can check your Python version by running:

```
python --version
```

Upgrade pip to the latest version:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Then, you can install TensorFlow

```
pip install tensorflow[and-cuda]
```

Please make sure to create a new virtual environment or activate your virtual environment.

```
import os

# Set TensorFlow log level to suppress warnings and info messages
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'

# Now you can import and use TensorFlow
import tensorflow as tf
```

Adding `os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'` will hide TensorFlow's warning messages.

Then you are ready to go.

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.sysconfig.get_build_info())

physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
print(physical_devices)
```

Here is the output

```
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Till 19/02/2024, default tensorflow 2.15 via pip3 is still not working. if you do as @arivero said, output is the same.

Luckily, i found this [post](https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/tensorflow-2-14-and-cuda-12-status/19725/3) in tensorflow forum, just install tf-nightly and it can find the gpu finally.[image: from tensorflow forum]

Comment: and one more thing: tensorflow==2.15.0.post1 also works for me

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35675477)

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any combination for Python 3.9 on RHEL 9 with CUDA 12.3 with NVIDIA L40, even with TF-nightly:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
2024-02-20 12:27:53.354867: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
2024-02-20 12:27:53.392552: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:9261] Unable to register cuDNN factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one has already been registered
2024-02-20 12:27:53.392593: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_fft.cc:607] Unable to register cuFFT factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuFFT when one has already been registered
2024-02-20 12:27:53.393695: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1515] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered
2024-02-20 12:27:53.399758: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 AVX512F AVX512_VNNI AVX512_BF16 AVX_VNNI AMX_TILE AMX_INT8 AMX_BF16 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2024-02-20 12:27:54.011008: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
>>> print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
2024-02-20 12:27:59.889455: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:2256] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
Num GPUs Available:  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometime if you install tensorflow[and-cuda] with some specific version like `tensorflow[and-cuda]==2.12.0` then it didn't install the required dependencies that are required to configure the GPU with tensorflow

please use

- `*pip install tensorflow[and-cuda]`
  instead of
- `pip install tensorflow[and-cuda]==2.12.0`
  Make sure to install the required drivers and libraries from the official tensorflow site

https://gist.github.com/neouranos/51dd12d9471eb73b2348d373b605b45a