# Windows 11 WSL2 Bash: Errors when running `python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"`. How to resolve them?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to run tensorflow with GPU.  When I run this command in Bash:

```
`python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"`
```

I get these errors:

```
2023-11-11 00:37:43.966691: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:111] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
2023-11-11 00:37:43.990298: I tensorflow/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:28] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
2023-11-11 00:37:44.097546: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:9342] Unable to register cuDNN factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one has already been registered
2023-11-11 00:37:44.097594: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_fft.cc:609] Unable to register cuFFT factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuFFT when one has already been registered
2023-11-11 00:37:44.097683: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1518] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered
2023-11-11 00:37:44.166160: I tensorflow/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:28] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
2023-11-11 00:37:44.167118: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 AVX_VNNI FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-11-11 00:37:45.042894: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
2023-11-11 00:37:45.558748: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:880] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2023-11-11 00:37:45.558921: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:2211] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
[]
```

Sorry about the long list of errors or warnings, but I really do not know which to resolve first or how to resolve them.

I've tried the following:

#### 2023-11-11 00:37:43.966691: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:111]

- I can try `export TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0` to remove this based on ChatGPT's suggestion, but based on its explanation, the slightly different numerical results does not explain if TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS should be changed:

> The warning you're seeing is related to TensorFlow's use of oneDNN (formerly known as MKL-DNN), which is a highly optimized library for deep learning operations. The warning is informing you that custom operations from oneDNN are enabled, and as a result, you might observe slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders.

- The first Google result for this error is this website: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/61700.  However, I also do not know where to begin looking to know if I should resolve this issue on this webpage.

#### 2023-11-11 00:37:43.990298: I tensorflow/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:28]

- This is a problem I spent a lot of time on due to the long installation processes.  I tried the commands at this link: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions.
- Running this `nvidia-smi` shows this:

[nvidia-smi output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nqrW.png)

- After running this: `pip install tensorflow[and-cuda]`, I ran this: `python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"`.  This is how I got these errors.
- I've also tried this code: `nvcc --version`, obtained from: [Cuda 12 + tf-nightly 2.12: Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used, while every checking is fine and in torch it works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75614728/cuda-12-tf-nightly-2-12-could-not-find-cuda-drivers-on-your-machine-gpu-will).  I was prompted by Bash to run: `sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit`.  This also took a long time and `nvcc --version` got this output:

  nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
  Copyright (c) 2005-2021 NVIDIA Corporation
  Built on Thu_Nov_18_09:45:30_PST_2021
  Cuda compilation tools, release 11.5, V11.5.119
  Build cuda_11.5.r11.5/compiler.30672275_0