# Unable to use tensorflow with GPU. Error: Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.7'. Export LD_LIBRARY_PATH could not solve issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, nvidia, tensorrt

I am currently using NVIDIA-SMI 495.29.05, Driver Version: 495.29.05 and CUDA Version: 11.5. Alongside, I am using python3.10 and Tensorflow==2.11.0 (the highest version of TF that's compatible with my CUDA) for my conda virtual environment.

I have tried to run `pip install tensorrt==8.5.1.7`, `pip install nvidia-tensorrt`, and running the commands `ln -s libnvinfer.so.8 libnvinfer.so.7`, `ln -s libnvinfer_plugin.so.8 libnvinfer_plugin.so.7` and `ln -s libcudart.so.12 libcudart.so.11.0` in the following directories:

/home/user/anaconda3/envs/myenvi/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorrt/
/home/user/anaconda3/envs/myenvi/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nvidia/cuda_runtime/lib/

I have also to export the above directories using: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:`

The steps I have followed are based on:

[Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.7'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74956134/could-not-load-dynamic-library-libnvinfer-so-7)

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/57679

I have also tried the following:

```
>>> from tensorflow.python.compiler.tensorrt import trt_convert as trt
>>> trt.trt_utils._pywrap_py_utils.get_linked_tensorrt_version()
(7, 2, 2)
```

My understanding is that Tensorflow==2.11.0 wants Tensorrt==7.2.2. However, I am unable to find this version and am unsure if this will be compatible with my CUDA (11.5).

Note: I am using a conda virutal environment (myenvi) and **do not have permission to use sudo**
My conda base environment uses Python3.11 and Tensorflow2.14, which is not compatible CUDA11.5.

My ultimate aim is to be able to use Tensorflow and utilise my GPU.

**Error:**

```
2023-10-18 10:47:25.017773: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-10-18 10:47:25.940716: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.7'; dlerror: libnvinfer.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: :/home/user/anaconda3/envs/myenvi/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorrt/:/home/user/anaconda3/envs/myenvi/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nvidia/cuda_runtime/lib/
2023-10-18 10:47:25.940841: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.7'; dlerror: libnvinfer_plugin.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: :/home/user/anaconda3/envs/myenvi/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorrt/:/home/user/anaconda3/envs/myenvi/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nvidia/cuda_runtime/lib/
2023-10-18 10:47:25.940856: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly.
```